# Cross product characteristic

Tags: cross-product

Is $(kA)\times B = A \times(Bk) = k*(A\times B) $

Im not sure if this holds everytime
With k being a scalar and x the cross product,

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You can check things like this by writing out the formula for the cross product, and doing so will help you learn the formula at the same time. By the way, we usually write $kB$ rather than $Bk$, i.e., scalar-by-vector multiplication is typically defined "on the left".

Comment: The cross product of two vectors can be expressed as a certain matrix determinant. What happens to the determinant of a matrix when you multiply one of its rows by $k$?